# How can I record a podcast?

Tags: windows-xp, podcasts, audacity

There are a couple of podcasts I have heard that I would like to record. How can I do this? I have Audacity, will this help?

I am using Windows XP

The solution I found uses the Stereo Mix option: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080702070019AAVf5fp

Comment: Your wording is a little ambiguous.  Do you want to be able to record someone else's podcasts or to create a couple of your own?

Comment: Am I missing something? If you've heard these podcasts can you not simply re download them from wherever you got them in the first place?

Comment: @Mokubai: These will not be there for much longer. I would like to have them

Comment: They are still stored as mp3s or video files and as such you can keep them as long as you like.  I suspect you question should actually be "Where does program X store the podcasts I download so that I can copy them?"

Comment: Now that is interesting. Can you direct me to where they might be saved??

Comment: I have searched my hard drive. They are nowhere to be found.

Comment: What program are you using and what podcasts?

Comment: THanks all. I've edited my answer to include the solution I found: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080702070019AAVf5fp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to listen to the Podcast and record it in real-time by hitting Record in Audacity to record "What You Hear".

If you're having trouble check out the Audacity Team's "[FAQ: How to record the speaker output](http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=4826)".

(Short-form blurb, see full text at link for full info):

> One of our most common questions is "How do I record sound from
>   YouTube or other streaming videos?" or "How can I copy audio from
>   files that Audacity doesn't recognize?" The answer to both questions
>   is to record the speaker output as the sound is playing.
>   Unfortunately, this is not always as trivial as it first appears to
>   be...
>
> So, putting aside any conspiracy theories or cries of incompetence,
>   there are three different ways to record this kind of audio...
>
> 1. Select it as an input in Audacity and click 'Record.'
> 2. Plug in a "loop-back" cable.
> 3. Obtain new hardware or software.

Another utility specifically meant for recording 'everything' is [Total Recorder](http://www.highcriteria.com/):

> An ideal tool for recording streaming audio, Mic input, or Line-in
>   input from external devices connected to your PC. Video Pro Edition
>   also allows you record video from screen or a video device like web
>   cam or TV tuner. Convenient and powerful scheduler allows you to
>   record when you can't be at your computer. The functionality of
>   background recording makes the process of recording streaming audio
>   and video handy and efficient!

If you want to just 'rip it', without listening, that will be more difficult and will depend on the source, the type of podcast, etc.

Comment: this is one of my favorite features of Audacity. +1 for providing a link to docs, I've been looking for those

Comment: "What you hear" is driver dependent, not all drivers will provide it.